# Re-write write-protected file

Tags: python, linux, bash, snakemake

Every 4 hours files are updated with new information if needed - i.e. if any new information has been processed for that particular file (files correspond to people).

I'm running this command to convert my .stp files (those being updated every 4 hours) to .xml files.

```
rule convert_waveform_stp:
    input:  '/data01/stpfiles/{file}.Stp'
    output: '/data01/workspace/bm_data/xmlfiles/{file}.xml'
    shell:
        '''
        mono /data01/workspace/bm_software/convert.exe {input} -o {output}
        '''
```

My script is in `Snakemake` (python based) but I'm running the `convert.exe` through a shell command.

I'm getting an error on the ones already processed using convert.exe. They are saved by `convert.exe` as write-protected and there is no option to bypass this within the executable itself.

Error Message:

```
ProtectedOutputException in line 14 of /home/Snakefile:
Write-protected output files for rule convert_waveform_stp:
/data01/workspace/bm_data/xmlfiles/PID_1234567.xml
```

I'd still like them to be write-protected but would also like to be able to update them as needed.

Is there something I can add to my shell command to write over the write protected files?

Comment: Do you understand what write protected means?

Comment: Yes. I know this isn't really the best set-up.
Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: Just remove the write protection and put it back later.

Comment: How can I remove it within my shell command? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at the os standard library package:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html?highlight=chmod#os.chmod

It allows for chmod with the following caveat:

> Although Windows supports chmod(), you can only set the file’s read-only flag with it (via the `stat.S_IWRITE` and `stat.S_IREAD` constants or a corresponding integer value). All other bits are ignored.

@VickiT05, I thought you wanted it in python.  Try this:

Check the original file permission with

```
ls -l [your file name]

stat -c %a [your file name]
```

Change the protection to with

```
chmod 777 [your file name]
```

change back to original file mode or whatever mode you want

```
chmod [original file protection mode] [your file name]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there an equivalent command for linux shell command?

Comment: Thank you @ivan7707

I did originally ask for python, you're correct.

But after changing a few things around I ended up needed it in bash script.